# Fading Toolbar effect not working

Tags: java, android, github, toolbar, android-toolbar

I'm using code from [this Gist](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) and [this is what I am trying to achieve](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/images/demo10.gif) (a fading ToolBar). However, when I start up my app I get the following error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference`

This is referring to the following line of code which is also on line 54 of [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/FlexibleSpaceWithImageRecyclerViewActivity.java), as well as here:

```
headerView.getLayoutParams().height = mFlexibleSpaceImageHeight;
```

When I comment out that line of code, the error stops appearing, but I don't get the fading effect I want; instead, the RecyclerView appears above the toolbar. The code I used is exactly the same (I've triple checked) as the following:

- [XML Activity Layout file](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/res/layout/activity_flexiblespacewithimagerecyclerview.xml)
- [Activity](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/FlexibleSpaceWithImageRecyclerViewActivity.java)
- [Base Activity](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/BaseActivity.java)
- [dimens.xml](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/res/values/dimens.xml)
- [recycler_header.xml](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/res/layout/recycler_header.xml)
- [padding.xml](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/res/layout/padding.xml)

Here's the problematic scrolling effect:
[image] [image]
The image behind the list is inside of the toolbar; that image, along with the toolbar should be in front of the list. The green bar in the other picture where I have scrolled further down the list is the toolbar - as you can see, the intended effect is not being achieved.